# Use cron or a java loop with a sleeping process

Tags: java, cron

I am trying to find the better way to update my database.

I have two solution but I don't know which is the less demanding.

The first one is to create a java program with a Thread.sleep and an infinite loop.

The second way is always with a java program but no thread sleep and infinite loop, just the update program and I execute this program using cron.

Thanks for your help

Comment: I'd like to have the less demanding in resources solution or an other one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"No thread sleep" + cron is simpler and easier to maintain:

- Your program does just one main thing - updates the database.
- Scheduling is delegated to cron. You are more flexible in configuration and do not need to write extra code to support "scheduling"